# log4j2 stop printing thread information from dependencies

Tags: java, log4j2

When running my project I am getting a lot of logs from Threads:

```
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @605ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
[INFO ] 2021-03-02 09:14:21,111 - My Project is running at http://127.0.1.1:8989
[Thread-1] WARN org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Ignoring deprecated socket close linger time
[Thread-1] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - == Spark has ignited ...
[Thread-1] INFO spark.embeddedserver.jetty.EmbeddedJettyServer - >> Listening on 0.0.0.0:8989
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.12.v20180830; built: 2018-08-30T13:59:14.071Z; git: 27208684755d94a92186989f695db2d7b21ebc51; jvm 1.8.0_282-b08
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.session - node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@5c6d6dd6{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8989}
[Thread-1] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @691ms
```

How can I ignore these threads? Below is my log4j2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="logPath">logs</Property>
        <Property name="rollingFileName">my-project</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%highlight{%-5level}] %d{DEFAULT}%notEmpty{ - %msg}%n%throwable" />
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="rollingFile" fileName="${logPath}/${rollingFileName}.log" filePattern="${logPath}/${rollingFileName}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%highlight{%-5level}] %d{DEFAULT}%notEmpty{ - %msg}%n%throwable" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true" />
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="server" level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="rollingFile"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I am using Flogger with log4j2 backend

Answer (score 1):

Most likely those other messages are being logged with something other than the Log4j API and you don't have your application set up to bridge them to Log4j 2. For example, if they are using the SLF4J API then you need to include log4j-slf4j-impl as a dependency and remove any other SLF4J implementations that may be present.